# What's "this" used for?

Tags: c#

I read some c# codes and can not understand the "this" key word in the function parameter? Could somebody tell me what it is used for? Thanks.

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static void InvokeIfNeeded(this Control ctl,
        Action doit)
    {
        if (ctl.InvokeRequired)
            ctl.Invoke(doit);
        else
            doit();
    }

    public static void InvokeIfNeeded<T>(this Control ctl,
        Action<T> doit, T args)
    {
        if (ctl.InvokeRequired)
            ctl.Invoke(doit, args);
        else
            doit(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's used to specify a type on which the [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) operates. That is, `public static void InvokeIfNeeded(this Control ctl, Action doit)` "adds" an `InvokeIfNeeded` method to `Control` class (and all derived classes). This method, however, can only be used if you explicitly import the namespace of a class they are declared in into your scope.

Comment: Thanks for the link, helped me understand a lot better.

Answer (score 3):

It signifies an extension method.  In the example you gave, any Control object will have the method InvokeIfNeeded(Action doit) available to use.  This is in addition to all the methods that a Control already has.

Answer (score 2):

It is used to define an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) for a given type.

Answer (score 1):

the static declaration of the method and the this modifier passed in signifies a Extension method where all Control objects will have these methods added on as if they were initially built that way.

i.e:
now you can do

```
Control myControl = new Control();

myControl.InvokeIfNeeded(myaction);
```

or

```
myControl.InvokeIfNeeded(myaction, args);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is used to mark the type of object that the extension method is being added to.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the 'this' keyword to a parameter like this will cause the method to be interpretted as an Extension method rather than a regular static method.

Answer (score 0):

The this modifier in a method declaration signifies that the method is an extension method.